# Disadvantages to running Ubuntu from a USB stick or SD card?

Tags: boot, usb, ssd

I'm buying a cheap barbone mini PC and I'm looking for a way to get around buying a SSD for it. I have a quality USB 3.0 stick here with 128GB which I'm not using atm. The PC also has USB 3.0. It also has 8GB of RAM. Should I install Ubuntu on the stick via another bootable stick or is it better to run Ubuntu from RAM with the boot-stick and reserve space on it for persistence? Will USB 3.0 be much slower than SATA? I'm guessing it's still faster than a HDD. I'm guessing running Ubuntu from SD is less desirable because of slower speed?

Comment: USB 3.0 is technically 480 megabits per second, while sata 6 is technically 3 Gigabits per second.  That means sata speed is about 6 times greater than your USB 3 port.   That being said, I've been running on a rotary drive with about 400 Mb per second and it goes plenty fast for me.

Comment: USB sticks and SD cards have a very limited amount of writes to it when compared to a traditional hard drive.  You can quickly wear out the media and end up with corrupt data.

Comment: @anonymous2 So it's correct that the stick will still be faster than a HDD?

Comment: Theoretically, if your drive is at MAX speed.  Practically, it depends also on your drive speed.  That is to say, SATA and USB are simply transfer protocols.  Their speed is like the number of lanes on a particular part of a freeway.  It may be the limiting factor; it may not.  If your hard drive doesn't go as fast as your USB stick's transfer rate, your USB stick could be faster.

Comment: @H3R3T1K No, HDD will be more than 6 times faster than the USB.

Comment: That's hard to believe.

Comment: Sorry, I read your comment wrong.  @Dorian is right, the HDD's max speed is higher than the USB stick.  But bear in mind, **it's all limited by the drive speed.**  If your drive is running 5400 turns per minute, you're only going to have say around 75MB/sec read whereas if you have 7200 turns per minute, you'll have more like 100MB/sec.

Comment: And those figures will totally depend on the drive.  I just threw out some random ones for comparison.

Comment: Do your full install to the stick then search here for "optimize usb" to see how to move as much as possible to ram.